# Declare typedef struct Variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, types

I have this typedef in my .h file

```
    typedef struct
{
    NSInteger openTime;
    NSInteger closeTime;
    } ShopHours;
```

Now I want to declare it in my .m file and then like you would a NSString that you want to use throughout the .m.

SO basically I want to initialize it, as an array of the typedef and then so I can assign it a vaule in my viewDidLoad method, as I see fit.

So basically I want to declare it like

```
ShopHours weekSchedule[] = {};
```

And then in viewDidLoad

```
weekSchedule[] = {//my data}
```

But when I try to declare and use it like this I get compile error

```
Field has incomplete type 'SHopHours[]'
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to know how big the weekSchedule variable is in order to put some memory aside for it.  You could declare it as shopHours weekSchedule[7]  for example.

Comment: What if the size is unknown?

Comment: if the size is unknown you have two options.  1.  use malloc() and a corresponding free() to allocate memory once you do know how large you want your array..  (which can work great, but also can be a real headache, depending how dynamic your model is..)  or 2. just declare an arbitrary number which is as big as it can possibly be (upper limit) like where I suggested 7 above.  This is by far the easier way..

Answer (score 0):

I tried, the problem was you need to decleare the size of the array first :

```
@interface LoginScreen (){
    ShopHours aa[5];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        aa[i].closeTime = 5+i;
        aa[i].openTime = 10 + i;
    }
}
```

In another method I logged it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Open Time %ld\n",(long)aa[i].openTime);
    NSLog(@"Close Time %ld\n",(long)aa[i].closeTime);
}
```

Works just fine.

If you want dynamic memory allocation,you can do it

```
@interface LoginScreen (){
    ShopHours *aa;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    aa = malloc(sizeof(ShopHours) * 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        aa[i].closeTime = 5+i;
        aa[i].openTime = 10 + i;
    }
}
```

Hope this helops.. :)

Comment: What if the size is unknown?